# How do screen readers handle nested aria-live with aria-atomic?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

How would a screen reader handle the case where you have an element with `aria-live` and `aria-atomic` inside another element with `aria-live` and `aria-atomic` and content changes inside the nested element?

Would it read both sections, reading the nested section twice?

HTML:

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
    Here is some text, <span>this itself may change</span>.  It is a large section of the page
    <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
        This is another part of the page that may change, it is also large. <span>This part may change too</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I ask is because I am using AngularJS to make a SPA that needs to be ADA-compliant. The site has a nested layout scheme where inner sections of the page would be changed without changing outer sections, but the outer sections may change a one point. Ideally, I would want only the inner section to be read when it changes. When the outer section changes, it would read all of it, once.

Comment: Wouldn't the way it was handled vary based on the specific screen reader being used?

Comment: I was hoping there would be some kind of standard or someone would be able to note what the different popular reads do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it's API specific:

```
Table of document change scenarios and events to be fired in each API

Scenario                MSAA + UIA Express event        MSAA + IAccessible2 event               ATK/AT-SPI event        Mac OS X Notification
When text is removed    EVENT_OBJECT_LIVEREGIONCHANGED  IAccessible2: IA2_EVENT_TEXT_REMOVED    text_changed::delete    If in a live region, AXLiveRegionChanged
When text is inserted   EVENT_OBJECT_LIVEREGIONCHANGED  IAccessible2: IA2_EVENT_TEXT_INSERTED   text_changed::insert    If in a live region, AXLiveRegionChanged
When text is changed    EVENT_OBJECT_LIVEREGIONCHANGED  IAccessible2: IA2_EVENT_TEXT_REMOVE     text_changed::delete    If in a live region, AXLiveRegionChanged
                                                        and IA2_EVENT_TEXT_INSERTED             and text_changed::insert
```

`aria-atomic` behavior is suggested:

> User agents SHOULD check the chain of ancestor elements for aria-atomic="true". If found, user agents SHOULD set the RELATION_MEMBER_OF relation to point to the ancestor that sets aria-atomic="true".

`aria-live` behavior is as well:

> User agents SHOULD ensure that an assistive technology, running in process can receive notification of a node being removed prior to removal. This allows an assistive technology, such as a screen reader, to refer back to the corresponding DOM node being deleted. This is important for live regions where removals are important. For example, a screen reader would want to notify a user that another user has left a chat room. The event in MSAA would be EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE. For ATK/AT-SPI this would be children_changed::remove. And in Mac OS X, the event is AXLiveRegionChanged. This also requires the user agent to provide a unique ID in the accessibility API notification identifying the unique node being removed.

**References**

- [WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices: Managing Dynamic Changes](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#docmgt_header)
- [Accelerated Dynamic Content Technical Style Guide](http://whatsock.com/tsg/)
- [WAI-ARIA 1.0 User Agent Implementation Guide: Changes to document content or node visibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-implementation/#mapping_events_visibility)
- [WAI-ARIA 1.0 Implementation Report](http://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/1.0/CR/implementation-report)
- [PDF Accessibility Notes](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/pdf_notes.html)
- [WAI-ARIA References](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/references)
- [Protocols and Formats Working Group (PFWG) Test Harness](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/testharness/)